How to create React component from name in right way
I have file with exports of some classes (react components), and I have some string which contain class name as string. So I need to create and render component by its name.
My variant:
import * as Formatter from "@/src/component/Formatter"

function isFormatterKey(key: string): key is keyof typeof Formatter {
    return Formatter.hasOwnProperty(key);
}

function getFormatter(type: string, name: string, meta: JsonApiMetaAttributeType): React.Component {
    let formatterName = capitalizeFirstLetter(meta[type][name].type) + 'Formatter'
    if (!isFormatterKey(formatterName)) {
        formatterName = 'StringFormatter'
    }
    return Formatter[formatterName]
}

{
    Object.keys(item.attributes).map((attrName: string) => {
        const FormatterComponent = getFormatter(item.type, attrName, meta)
        return (
            <td key={"data-cell-" + attrName}>
                <FormatterComponent>
                    {item.attributes[attrName]}
                </FormatterComponent2>                      
            </td>
        )
    })
}

But I have an error in my IDE:

TS2604: JSX element type FormatterComponent does not have any construct or call signatures.
TS2786: FormatterComponent cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type Component<{}, {}, any> is not a valid JSX element type.

Anyway, I feel like I do some bad code, and somewhere exists some pattern for this.

React Components can be defined in mainly two different ways:

Functional Components
Class Components

A Class Component will look something like this:
import React from 'react';

export class FormatterComponent extends React.Component<> {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
        example1:"",
        example2:"",
      };
  } 
  render(){
    return(<MustBeOneParentElement></MustBeOneParentElement>)
  }

}

If you're using TypeScript, you can define the the types for the props (first argument) and state (second argument) as interfaces within the <>.
A Functional Component will look something like this
import React from "react";

export const FormatterComponent = ({ props, go, here }) => {

    return(<MustBeOneParentElement></MustBeOneParentElement>)
}

In a Class component, you will be calling this.setState, and componentDidMount () lifecycle methods.
In a Functional component, you will be using useState() to use hooks to set state, and useEffect() rather than componentDidMount() Lifecycle methods.
Differences in importing Class and Functional Components
A class component is imported like so:
import {FormatterComponent} from "./path/to/FormatterComponent"

A functional component is imported like so:
import FormatterComponent from "./path/to/FormatterComponent"

I usually avoid default exports. You can also declare multiple components within the same file if it makes sense to do so. This will allow you to avoid making an import/export.
Futhermore
When you are passing arguments into a component, like in your FormatterComponent, you pass them using props.
So, if you want to pass an attrName, you would do:
<FormatterComponent attrname={item.attributes[attrName]}/>

Notice how if you put the slash before the end of the closing ">" you do not need a fully formed closing tag.

How does this address the question? Looks like an llm react primer. OP knows how to make components; issue is the mapping.

OP states "Anyway, I feel like I do some bad code, and somewhere exists some pattern for this." OP Provides no information on neither  nor . I see possible issues with defining the component, defining the types of the props and state, issues with importing the components, and i see issues with passing props to the component since  is not a , , or  etc tag. It is a poorly worded question and OP had 2 downvotes so I merely tried to offer assistance instead of ignoring him. basic practice of returning a single parent is present
